# mvn clean install fails for PL/Java on Postgres 9.5

Tags: java, postgresql

I am working on installing PL/Java on Postgres 9.5.

My setup is Postgres 9.5 on Centos 6.5 with Oracle-Java JDK 1.8.0_92

My install of Postgres was done from these yum-packages:

```
postgresql95
postgresql95-devel
postgresql95-libs
postgresql95-server
```

I list below a summary of my steps so far:

```
su - postgres
git clone https://github.com/tada/pljava
git checkout V1_5_0
mvn clean install
```

That seemed to work until I saw this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PostgreSQL PL/Java ................................. SUCCESS [ 16.707 s]
[INFO] PL/Java API ........................................ SUCCESS [  8.771 s]
[INFO] PL/Java backend Java code .......................... SUCCESS [  4.000 s]
[INFO] PL/Java backend native code ........................ FAILURE [ 13.560 s]
[INFO] PL/Java Deploy ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PL/Java Ant tasks .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] PL/Java examples ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PL/Java packaging .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 52.707 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-06T18:09:40-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-compile
(default-nar-compile) on project pljava-so: NAR: Compile failed: gcc
failed with return code 1 -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :pljava-so
```

I would welcome any clues and/or opinions about how to best debug this so that mvn clean install will run error free.

Comment: pljava-so failed to build. GCC might give you more information if you try compiling it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a shell command from root to fix it:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

That fixed it. Yay!

Comment: I am facing the same problem on Ubuntu. Can you suggest?